# Subversion: How to merge a specific commit

Tags: svn, merge

I have some commit on my branches. I want to merge the branches to trunk, but there have some commit that I don't merge to trunk on my branches. How do I do?

Comment: Do you mean that you have some commits that you don't want to merge in your trunk or that you have some conflicts when trying to merge your changes?

Comment: example,there have seven commit on my branches ,but I only want to merge three commit.

Comment: So You have to merge only specify revision. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326937/subversion-how-to-merge-only-specific-revisions-into-trunk-when-multiple-consec

Answer (score 54):

What you want to accomplish is usually called *cherrypicking* in version control systems.

Say that you want to merge revisions 345, 364 and 377 from your branch to trunk, you will do the following at the top level directory of a clean working copy of `trunk`:

```
svn merge -c345,364,377 ^/_your_branch_
```

on Windows `cmd` add quotes around the branch name:

```
svn merge -c345,364,377 "^/_your_branch_"
```

You can find more information in the corresponding [section of the SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking).

Comment: In the link, it looks like `^/trunk` is the source branch. So I think the example should be `svn merge -c345,364,377 ^/yourbranch` while having trunk checked out, right?

Comment: @Mark yes, absolutely, I've just updated the example. Thanks!

Answer (score 46):

Just to extend Yannick's answer.
When you can merge one/few specific commits from one to another branch you need(for example need merge commits r13 and r666 from branch '*from*' into branch '*to*'):

1. Check commits availability (just to ensure):

   ```
   svn diff -c 13,666 https://fullpathtoyourproject/branches/_from_
   ```
2. Swith on branch *to*:

   ```
   svn sw https://fullpathtoyourproject/branches/_to_
   ```
3. Merge commits

   ```
   svn merge -c 13,666 https://fullpathtoyourproject/branches/_from_
   ```

If you need get 'fullpathtoyourproject' just type:

```
svn info
```

In section URL you will see this path.

I prefer to use FULL url/path, cause personally relative path did not work for me on some projects.

Comment: This is a good answer because it explains the source and destination of the merge.

Answer (score 8):

If one has TortoiseSVN installed, below are the steps to merge a range of revisions from a branch to the other.

1. Have a local checkout of the branch to which you want to merge a range of revisions from a source branch.
2. Right Click inside root folder --> TortoiseSVN --> Merge
3. By default, "Merge a range of revisions" is clicked.
4. Click Next
5. Enter the URL to merge from
6. Enter the specific range of revisions you want to merge
7. One can also click Show log and select the desired revision or range of revisions
8. Click Test Merge to check if it merges desired revisions/files.
9. Click merge

Answer (score -9):

You can merge the commits you want with the revision number.

Comment: Yes, but, how??