# Using TortoiseSVN and Visual Studio Code, how do i merge some out of order changes from a dev branch to a stage branch?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-code, tortoisesvn

OK, here is my problem: I've got all sorts of new features on a page.html that i need to roll out on my dev branch, but i need to commit only some of those features to the stage branch, and they are out of order. How do i do this? Here's what i mean by out of order:

For example, on dev, i have widgets 1-4 on page.html and on stage, only widget 1 is on page.html. Now a project manager wants widget 3 on page.html on stage, but not 4. So, it's out of order. How the heck do you do this?

I keep trying "Merge a range of revisions" but i don't think i'm on the right track.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Commit only parts of files](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html) feature for Tortoisesvn

Comment: [Subversion: How to merge a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556646/subversion-how-to-merge-a-specific-commit/11557089)

Comment: Is there a solution to compare directories and then, within the same interface, cherry pick the changes from one directory (dev) to (stage) ?